# disable default tooltip am5hierarchy.partition. amcharts

Tags: tooltip, hierarchy, amcharts

I want to disable tooltip in am5hierarchy.partition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ZyK.png)
I show original code:`

```
// Create wrapper container
var container = root.container.children.push(am5.Container.new(root, {
  width: am5.percent(100),
  height: am5.percent(100),
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));


// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/hierarchy/#Adding
var series = container.children.push(am5hierarchy.Partition.new(root, {
  singleBranchOnly: false,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  downDepth: 1,
  initialDepth: 10,
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "name",
  childDataField: "children"
}));
```

`
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
series.set(
  "tooltip",
  am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    forceHidden: true,
  })
);
```

Hope it helps. I spent days to tune related config.